# KendoUI - Chart data labels

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Is is possible to for the KendoUI Chart (Area) to have multiple data labels or even a concatenation of two? I need to display both a value and a percentage for each data point. Is this something that would need to be handled on the data source side or is it on the view?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: already tried something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use templates to format both labels and tooltips; see [labels.template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-categoryAxis.labels.template) and [tooltip.template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-series.tooltip.template).

Answer (score 0):

The key is to reference the Property you want using dataItem ex:

**dataItem.TotalDollars**

```
template: "${ category } - #= kendo.format('{0:C}', dataItem.TotalDollars)#"
```

The answer above wont really help unless you have a strong understanding of the Kendo UI framework. I was having a similar issue and before I found my answer I found this question. I circled back because the answer is simple and some simple example code is really simple. Lets save everyone some clicks.

**DATA RESPONSE FROM REMOTE DATA (copy and past for local binding):**

```
[
{
"ProgramName":"Amarr Garage Doors",
"PercentageShare":50.12,
"TotalDollars":5440.000000
},
{
"ProgramName":"Monarch Egress Thermal Hinge C",
"PercentageShare":4.64,
"TotalDollars":504.000000
},
{
"ProgramName":"Monarch Egress Window Wells",
"PercentageShare":15.73,
"TotalDollars":1707.000000
},
{
"ProgramName":"Monarch Premier V Egress Windo",
"PercentageShare":16.25,
"TotalDollars":1764.000000
},
{
"ProgramName":"Organized Living Shelftech Ven",
"PercentageShare":13.27,
"TotalDollars":1440.000000
}
]
```

**Chart Generation Code: **

```
function createChart() {
    $("#SubmissionSummaryByProgramChart").kendoChart({
        title: {
            text: "Breakdown by Program"
        },
        legend: {
            position: "right"
        },
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "GetFooData",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        Year : 2014,
                        Quarter : 1,
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: "pie",
            field: "PercentageShare",
            categoryField: "ProgramName"
        }],
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            template: "${ category } - #= kendo.format('{0:C}', dataItem.TotalDollars)#"
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(createChart);
```